# create list with elements which are sublists that alternate between elements in sublists from two other lists

Tags: python, algorithm, list-comprehension, nested-lists

The title is a bit weird but essentially I need to take two lists:

```
list1 = [['1', '1', '1', '1'], ['2', '2', '2', '2'], ['3', '3', '3', '3']]
list2 = [['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b']]
```

and then alternate between the elements in the sub-lists of the two lists and create sub-lists as elements in a new list whose sub-lists are the alternated elements from above

```
list3 = [['1', 'a', '1', 'a', '1', 'a', '1'], ['1', 'b', '1', 'b', '1', 'b', '1'], ['2', 'a', '2', 'a', '2', 'a', '2'], ... ]
```

right now my code is:

```
def foo(array1, array2):
    i = 1
    for sublist1 in array1:
        for sublist2 in array2:
            for val in sublist2:
                sublist1.insert(i, val)
                i += 2
        i = 1
    return array1
```

and I'm getting the output:

```
[['1', 'a', '1', 'a', '1', 'a', '1', 'b', 'b', 'b'], ['2', 'a', '2', 'a', '2', 'a', '2', 'b', 'b', 'b'], ['3', 'a', '3', 'a', '3', 'a', '3', 'b', 'b', 'b']]
```

the thing is that I'm working with much smaller lists as a proof of concept right now but the final algorithm will need to be able to do this for lists with millions of sub-lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `itertools` for the task:

```py
from itertools import product, zip_longest

list1 = [["1", "1", "1", "1"], ["2", "2", "2", "2"], ["3", "3", "3", "3"]]
list2 = [["a", "a", "a"], ["b", "b", "b"]]

out = []
for c in product(list1, list2):
    out.append([v for c in zip_longest(*c) for v in c if v is not None])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    ["1", "a", "1", "a", "1", "a", "1"],
    ["1", "b", "1", "b", "1", "b", "1"],
    ["2", "a", "2", "a", "2", "a", "2"],
    ["2", "b", "2", "b", "2", "b", "2"],
    ["3", "a", "3", "a", "3", "a", "3"],
    ["3", "b", "3", "b", "3", "b", "3"],
]
```

---

**Note:** If there's `None` in any of your sub-lists, use other `fillvalue=` in [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variation on itertools' [`roundrobin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))

   
out = [list(roundrobin(a, b)) for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Output:

```
[['1', 'a', '1', 'a', '1', 'a', '1'], ['2', 'b', '2', 'b', '2', 'b', '2']]
```

Comment: Maybe just *pip install more_itertools* to use it then.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `product` to get the Cartesian product of the two lists, and then `zip` and chain them:

```py
result = [list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*p))) for p in product(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

use deepcopy:

```py
from copy import deepcopy

def foo(list1, list2):
    ans = []
    for L1 in list1:
        for L2 in list2:
            L3 = deepcopy(L1)
            for i, val in enumerate(L2):
                L3.insert(i * 2 + 1, val)
            ans.append(L3)
    return ans
```